Push offset for a function on the stack
I'm trying to understand the assembly code for ntdll!ExecuteHandler2 function :
ntdll!ExecuteHandler2:
775c7193 55              push    ebp
775c7194 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
775c7196 ff750c          push    dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
775c7199 52              push    edx
775c719a 64ff3500000000  push    dword ptr fs:[0]
775c71a1 64892500000000  mov     dword ptr fs:[0],esp
775c71a8 ff7514          push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
775c71ab ff7510          push    dword ptr [ebp+10h]
775c71ae ff750c          push    dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
775c71b1 ff7508          push    dword ptr [ebp+8]
775c71b4 8b4d18          mov     ecx,dword ptr [ebp+18h]
775c71b7 ffd1            call    ecx
775c71b9 648b2500000000  mov     esp,dword ptr fs:[0]
775c71c0 648f0500000000  pop     dword ptr fs:[0]
775c71c7 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
775c71c9 5d              pop     ebp
775c71ca c21400          ret     14h

im using windbg on windows7 to trace all instructions, the fourth instruction i dont understand it, so the author of the course said
775c7199 52              push    edx


The second PUSH instruction appears to place an offset into the
ntdll!ExecuteHandler2 function on the stack:

so what does this mean ? and why we do this ? at the time of the instruction the value of edx is
0:010> t
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=77e15aed edx=775c71cd esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=775c7199 esp=01d1f5e4 ebp=01d1f5e8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246
ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x6:
775c7199 52              push    edx

0:010> u @edx
ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x3a:
775c71cd 8b4c2404        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+4]
775c71d1 f7410406000000  test    dword ptr [ecx+4],6
775c71d8 b801000000      mov     eax,1
775c71dd 7512            jne     ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x5e (775c71f1)
775c71df 8b4c2408        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+8]
775c71e3 8b542410        mov     edx,dword ptr [esp+10h]
775c71e7 8b4108          mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx+8]
775c71ea 8902            mov     dword ptr [edx],eax


It is an offset into this function (or rather into a separate function without a public name that apparently deals with exceptions caused by whatever code this function calls) but that address had to be passed from the caller of this function and not set by itself. Think of it as an additional parameter for the function beyond the stack ones. This is not a standard call convention but then this function, and its callers, are not C code.

@AndreyTurkin, as i understand you, in edx there is a function and we need to pass it as an argument to the function ntdll!ExecuteHandler2 ? so its call back function in edx ? did i understand it wrong ?

Sort of, yes. edx is an argument for ExecuteHandler2, and it can be seen as a callback of sorts except it is not called directly from ExecuteHandler2. To answer your original question - push edx merely uses whatever what passed down to the function which happens to point right after the ExecuteHandler2 code. As to "why we do this" - the function temporarily installs a SEH handler so that if the actual callback (call ecx) fails that fail is handled by that function that was passed down.

@AndreyTurkin thank you so much, it clear now for me .
